# How do I find out what Amazon has stored?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I would like to control/recover/delete files on Amazon.
How is this done?

Answer (score 2):

Easy, assuming you're using your own AWS account.  Login here: http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/ then click the "Sign in to the AWS Management Console" at the very top.  Select the appropriate bucket and bam - there's your stuff.

Alternatively, if you didn't create an Amazon Web Services account, you're probably using the AWS account of the developer of whatever app you're using to store stuff there.  In which case, you'll need to ask them.

Sorry, the question is a bit vague, so I gave two answers.  If I misunderstood, could you try rephrasing the question with a little more detail?